# Postgres: how to create a not in statement for s json array element

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

Extract of the Table schema for the first table named `dev`,

| dev id | Employee Name | JSON ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ef7fd5df-7881-470d-bc7d-846211df0344 | Tom | {"sourcedevIds":[],"sourcedepartmentId":["edfgerg-4534-4frg-5665-bgfbn645","546t5gg43-78ik-m78i-345t34e-h56e5"]} |
| 345r34-2345-56yt-78ui-343trtrfg567 | John | {"sourcedevIds":["wedfrtg-7890-3trr-6887-rte45R3"],"sourcedepartmentId":["werefr-3454-56tyy-2343-rt456y","34e27-2343-456te-23ewd-89iol","343rfe-34rde-4reft-3edq-343r322"]} |

**Note:** the uuid are just dummy values here.

So what I need to do is create a `not in` statement or similar to get only the employee names that does not have the below uuid's(note:dummy values added in the query) under  `dev.JSON ID ->> 'sourcedepartmentId'` as one of its JSON data(i.e uuid value) in the element.

For example the current query I wrote is as below,

```
(dev.JSON ID ->> 'sourcedepartmentId')::uuid not in 
                                  (  '34e27-2343-456te-23ewd-89iol',
                                     '3retwut5-78ut-42dw-wu67-w234rtyu7',
                                     '5tvgr23t-23detrg-34fe-4gt66-23edw345',
                                     '546t5gg43-78ik-m78i-345t34e-h56e5',
                                     '343rfe-34rde-4reft-3edq-343r322'
                                    )
```

The error I get is,

```
invalid input syntax for type uuid: "["edfgerg-4534-4frg-5665-bgfbn645"]"
```

Then I tried the below,

```
json_array_elements_text((dev.JSON ID ->> 'sourcedepartmentId')::json) not in 
                                  (  '34e27-2343-456te-23ewd-89iol',
                                     '3retwut5-78ut-42dw-wu67-w234rtyu7',
                                     '5tvgr23t-23detrg-34fe-4gt66-23edw345',
                                     '546t5gg43-78ik-m78i-345t34e-h56e5',
                                     '343rfe-34rde-4reft-3edq-343r322'
                                    )
```

Which I think the first query before not in results with only the first value of the array(I tried to query the value returned by this and yes it just returns the first value of the array only. While there are other values as well.)

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

---

The not in statement after the solution c to look into the sub id's

```
(dev.subID ->> 'sourcedepartmentId' ->>0)::uuid not in 
                               (  '34e27-2343-456te-23ewd-89iol',
                                  '3retwut5-78ut-42dw-wu67-w234rtyu7',
                                  '5tvgr23t-23detrg-34fe-4gt66-23edw345',
                                  '546t5gg43-78ik-m78i-345t34e-h56e5',
                                  '343rfe-34rde-4reft-3edq-343r322'
                                )
```

Also, Plese note that `d.json_id -> 'sourcedepartmentId'` would have values as below,

- with just one uuid value. Example: `["ba18e414-92d3-446b-91b4-67050f891121"]` or
- multiple uuid values as an array. Example: `["45b90b79-1151-4d8c-8785-4886607524bd", "70b9de47-5e10-42a5-bf30-81c0d4efe6bd", "e1f30960-06eb-41b4-9ca7-49b389defcab", "5cb85419-7fb7-45bd-ae8c-46b3d7ab9154"]` or
- null or empty value.

Thanks

Comment: Are you aware that you can never get good performance for such a query with such a data model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do that using a NOT EXISTS condition that checks the presence using an `IN` condition:

```
select *
from dev d
where not exists (select *
                  from jsonb_array_elements_text(d.json_id -> 'sourcedepartmentId') as s(dept_id)
                  where s.dept_id in ('34e27-2343-456te-23ewd-89iol',
                                      '3retwut5-78ut-42dw-wu67-w234rtyu7',
                                      '5tvgr23t-23detrg-34fe-4gt66-23edw345',
                                      '546t5gg43-78ik-m78i-345t34e-h56e5',
                                      '343rfe-34rde-4reft-3edq-343r322')
                  )
```

This assumes that the column `json_id` is defined as `jsonb` (which it should be). If it's not, use `json_array_elements_text()` instead.

---

If you also need to cope with the fact that `sourcedepartmentId` *could* be a single value instead of an array, you need to make the inner query more complex handling the two cases differently.

```
select *
from dev d
where not exists (select *
                  from ( 
                    select * 
                    from jsonb_array_elements_text(d.json_id -> 'sourcedepartmentId')
                    where jsonb_typeof(d.json_id -> 'sourcedepartmentId') = 'array'
                    union all
                    select d.json_id ->> 'sourcedepartmentId'
                    where jsonb_typeof(d.json_id -> 'sourcedepartmentId') = 'string'
                  )  as s(dept_id)
                  where s.dept_id in (....)
                 )
```

Again if you are not using the recommended `jsonb` type, you will have to use `json_typeof()` instead.

Comment: I tried this an getting the error `cannot call json_array_elements_text on a scalar`. Any help with this, please?

Comment: @jaesonBernardsha: then you have rows where `sourcedepartmentId` does not contain an array as its value but something else.

Comment: some rows might have only one UUID value and not an array. Would that might be the reason? Any idea to solve this issue

Comment: @jaesonBernardsha: sigh, the "joys" of de-normalized and inconsistent "data models" - see my edit on how to cope with that mess.

Comment: Yeah, ik. I have to work with data for the time being:). I tried your answer and I get the error `input of anonymous composite types is not implemented `. Any help with this?

Answer (score 1):

(a) `(dev.JSON ID ->> 'sourcedepartmentId')` returns a json array as a text with square brackets so that it can't be casted as a `uuid` and this raises the error you get.

(b) `json_array_elements_text(dev."JSON ID")` should return a set of text that can be casted  as `uuid`, but it cannot be directly inserted in the `WHERE` clause of a query because set-returning functions are not allowed in `WHERE`.

(c) One possible solution could be :

```
SELECT ...
  FROM dev
 CROSS JOIN LATERAL json_array_elements_text(dev."JSON ID" -> 'sourcedepartmentId') AS j(data)
 WHERE j.data :: uuid NOT IN (  '34e27-2343-456te-23ewd-89iol',
                                '3retwut5-78ut-42dw-wu67-w234rtyu7',
                                '5tvgr23t-23detrg-34fe-4gt66-23edw345',
                                '546t5gg43-78ik-m78i-345t34e-h56e5',
                                '343rfe-34rde-4reft-3edq-343r322'
                             )
```

(c) As explained by @Laurenz, this solution can't be really performant. There is no json operator equivalent to most of the [sql array operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html), so querying json arrays is usually not easy nor efficient.

(d) Storing the `sourcedepartmentId` data in a dedicated column of type `uuid[]` and with a dedicated `gin` index could be much more efficient when querying with the following condition :

```
NOT sourcedepartmentId && array['34e27-2343-456te-23ewd-89iol',
                                '3retwut5-78ut-42dw-wu67-w234rtyu7',
                                '5tvgr23t-23detrg-34fe-4gt66-23edw345',
                                '546t5gg43-78ik-m78i-345t34e-h56e5',
                                '343rfe-34rde-4reft-3edq-343r322'
                               ] :: uuid[]
```

(e) If you can't change the `dev` table definition, I would suggest to create a dedicated function that will convert the json array as a uuid array. Then this function can be used for indexing and querying your data :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION json_to_uuid_array(data json)
RETURNS uuid[] LANGUAGE sql AS
$$
  SELECT ARRAY(SELECT json_array_elements_text(data -> 'sourcedepartmentId')) :: uuid[] ;
$$ ;

CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS sourcedepartmentId ON dev USING gin (json_to_uuid_array("JSON ID")) ;

SELECT ...
  FROM dev
 WHERE NOT json_to_uuid_array(dev."JSON ID") 
       && array['34e27-2343-456te-23ewd-89iol',
                '3retwut5-78ut-42dw-wu67-w234rtyu7',
                '5tvgr23t-23detrg-34fe-4gt66-23edw345',
                '546t5gg43-78ik-m78i-345t34e-h56e5',
                '343rfe-34rde-4reft-3edq-343r322'
               ] :: uuid[] ;
```

Comment: Jaeson points out in his question that "Note: the uuid are just dummy values here". So I agree with @a_horse_with_no_name that if the real data in the real world are not uuids, then uuid[] must be replaced by text[]. But the rest of my answer is still relevant to me.

Comment: @Edouard Thanks so much for the help. But I tried the second option by adding it in the `And` clause. But I get only the first element in the array, not all the elements. which is very weird. this is what I wrote `json_array_elements_text((dev.JSON ID ->> 'sourcedepartmentId')::json)`. The result is just the first element in the array, while there are other elements as well.

Comment: `json_array_elements_text((dev.JSON ID ->> 'sourcedepartmentId')::json)`can be simplified as `json_array_elements_text(dev.JSON ID -> 'sourcedepartmentId')`. Can you update your question with the full query please ?

Comment: Hi @Edouard. I came across an issue, which is `json_array_elements_text((dev.JSON ID ->> 'sourcedepartmentId')::json)` doesnt actually looks for all the values after the not in statement. But just the first one. Is there any way I can add two cross join laterals or properly use a not in statement. The current one I am using is (dev.JSON ID ->> 'sourcedepartmentId' ->> 0)::uuid not in <a sub query statement>. Which again looks at the first UUID value only. Is there any way I look at all the values?  Also, I have the cross lateral join. So not sure whether I can use another one as well.

Comment: Did you test the solutions (c) and (e) from my answer above ? They should answer the issue you raise in your last comment.

Comment: I tried solution C. I have a `not in` statement as the one I have added to the bottom of description now. The `not` in statement is to look at the subid's as well. But very weirdly when I remove the above `not in` statement, I get the error `cannot calljson_array_elements_text on a scalar` for the solution c you provided. I dont understand at all why it's happening and how both separate functions are related. Any help on this, please?

Comment: @Edouard I think the error has always been there for the solution C, but never showed up because of the not in statement. Any idea on how to solve the error "cannot call json_array_elements_text on a scalar"

Comment: You get this error when `dev."JSON ID" -> 'sourcedepartmentId'` is not a json array. You can avoid this error by replacing `json_array_elements(...)` by `jsonb_path_query(dev."JSON ID" -> 'sourcedepartmentId', '$[*]')`

Comment: @Edouard I added jsonb_path_query(dev."JSON ID" -> 'sourcedepartmentId', '$[*]') , but I get the error `function json_path_query(json, unknown) does not exist `. Not sure what should I add to the `path jsonpath` instead. Any help with this please?

Comment: `jsonb` instead of `json` (you should not use json type). try : `jsonb_path_query(dev."JSON ID" -> 'sourcedepartmentId' :: jsonb, '$[*]' :: jsonpath)`

Comment: Tried that as well and got the error `invalid input syntax for type json`.

Comment: my query works well with your data sample (except for the format of your uuid values in the WHERE clause) see [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=4546f862d299ef7434b18b7c1ae4e6fc)

Comment: I beleive json_array_elements_text is not working is because sometimes in the json array there will be just one UUID value and null or empty values as well. So the resulting value for  dev."JSON ID" -> 'sourcedepartmentId' will be like this ["ba18e414-92d3-446b-91b4-67050f891121"] or null values for some rows and for some it will be a JSON array. Is there any way I could resolve this? Thanks

Comment: the only case where `json_array_elements_text(json_data)` doesn't work is when json_data is not a json array. If you have this case, then you can use `jsonb_path_query_text(json_data :: jsonb, '$[*]')` instead of `json_array_elements_text(json_data)`. If you need more help, then you must share your use case in [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=4546f862d299ef7434b18b7c1ae4e6fc)

Comment: The problem is as I stated above that `d.json_id -> 'sourcedepartmentId'` would have values as below,

   1) with just one uuid value. Example: ["ba18e414-92d3-446b-91b4-67050f891121"] or
    2) multiple uuid values as an array. Example: ["45b90b79-1151-4d8c-8785-4886607524bd", "70b9de47-5e10-42a5-bf30-81c0d4efe6bd", "e1f30960-06eb-41b4-9ca7-49b389defcab", "5cb85419-7fb7-45bd-ae8c-46b3d7ab9154"] or
    3) null or empty value.                                                                                                 
The use case is the same as before.